# Sending a .txt file attachment via phpmailer is messing the output format of the text file

Tags: php, encoding, attachment, phpmailer, contenttype

I have an application that generates a .txt file and everything is perfect , the .txt file is able to keep its current formatting up until i decide to attach and send it via email.

when a user receives it ,the .txt file has lost its format ....

i have played around with phpmailer word_wrap method , changed encoding to all of them and even changed isHTML to false ,just to be sure..... but seems like 2 days fighting a losing war ....

Please note: The generated .txt file is able to retain its format ,only when i try to send it via phpmailer.....

Comment: Give header in Mailer Function and set it to Deposition.

Comment: What do mean with format when talking about it a `txt` file? How is the content altered?

Comment: Don't try to post code in comments - edit your question. You need to post your code for us to be able to help you. I assume you've already read [this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: the code to send the txt is not the issue ? i am able to attach it just fine but the issue is when i receive the txt file ,the text inside the file wont be aligned as it was before sending it

Comment: Through continously trying to find the issue , i have found the culprit but i am not able to resolve it yet and thats where i need your help..Unix and windows use different EOL and when i checked the documents using Notepad++ , the one that doesnt lose its "word alignment" has got windows/Dos EOL and the one that changes has got Unix EOL ....can anyone help me.I have tried changing the phpmailer class LE to \r\n with no success ,what am i missing

Comment: Managed to work around the issue and i am still trying to understand how it was affecting my txt file but somehow this was the issue.I am using git so whenever i pushed my files from my windows development environment to the linux apache server ,my git was warning me of below "LF will be replaced by CRLF in git
" so i then configured this on both systems $ git config core.autocrlf false and voila ...everything works perfectly now